# Floating text on bottom of image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create something like this:
[image: What I am trying to create]
But I just can't get it right. Here is what I have so far: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q74CF/). 
HTML:

```
<div class="review">
    <div class="review-head">
        <h2> Batman Arkham Knight Review </h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.review-head {
    height: 20em;
    background: url(http://www.flickeringmyth.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Arkham-Knight2.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
h2 {
    color: white;
    vertical-align: center;
}
```

What am I missing here? 
If it matters or not, I'm trying to put the image inside a Bootstrap panel.
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give your `review-head` element a `position`. This will allow you to position the `h2` within it.

```css
.review-head {
    height: 20em;
    background: url(http://www.flickeringmyth.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Arkham-Knight2.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}
h2 {
    color: white;
    vertical-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="review">
    <div class="review-head">
        <h2> Batman Arkham Knight Review </h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `h2` to this:

```
h2 {
    color: white;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

My suggestion is to use a `div` element with id or class to achieve that. E.g `<div class="imgTextFooter" ></div>` and apply here the style you want :)

Forgot to add that you have to add `position:relative` to `.review-head`

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q74CF/14/)

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
position: relative;
```

to the parent div.

Add

```
position: absolute; 
bottom: 0;
```

to the h2.